# Prove by induction: $E[\sum_{i=1}^nc_iU_i(X)]=\sum_{i=1}^nc_iE[U_i(X)]$ Please just check what I've done

Tags: probability, statistics, proof-verification, summation

Prove by induction:

$$E[\sum_{i=1}^nc_iU_i(X)]=\sum_{i=1}^nc_iE[U_i(X)]$$

Let me show you what I've done. I think I'm right:

$$n=1,$$ 
$$E[c_1U_1(X)] = c_1E[U_1(X)]$$

Okay so maybe this one looks a bit trivial
$$n=2,$$ 
$$E[c_1U_1(X)+c_2U_2(X)] = E[c_1U_1(X)] + E[c_2U_2(X)]$$

$$= c_1E[U_1(X)] + c_2E[U_2(X)]$$

Okay so now assume true for some $n$

Prove true for $n+1$

$$E[\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}c_iU_i(X)] = E[\sum_{i=1}^nc_iU_i(X) + c_{n+1}U_{n+1}(X)]$$

$$=E[\sum_{i=1}^nc_iU_i(X)] + E[c_{n+1}U_{n+1}(X)]$$

$$= \sum_{i=1}^nc_iE[U_i(X)] + c_{n+1}E[U_{n+1}(X)] \text{(By the Induction Assumption)}$$

$$= \sum_{i=1}^{n+1}c_iE[U_{n+1}(X)]$$

What I'm concerned about is whether it is right to make the assumption that you can take constants in and out of the Expected Value during this proof. Clearly you cannot make all of these kinds of assumptions regarding the summation sign?

Comment: Certainly, $cE(X) = E(cX),$ for a constant $a$ and a random variable $X$. What do you know about $E(X + Y)?$ What are $U_i$ and $X?$ The notation seems more complex than necessary; do you intend parentheses to indicate multiplication or a function?

Comment: It's a function (a new random variable in terms of a variable X). So if have a variable $X = $ error in size of a diameter in mm for example. You can create a p.m.f. etc out of it and work out expected values. So now let $U(X) = Y = 3x^2$ for example. Then if we had $-2mm$ and $2mm$ with separate probabilities but now when you use the function, they both become $12$ so you need to add the probabilities from both for this new variable

Comment: So if it is just another random variable such as X, surely $E[X+U(X)] = E[X] + E[U(X)]$ as well but I just wonder when they ask for a proof by induction which properties can be assumed and which ones we're precisely still needing to prove